# How do I get the name of the page I am on?

Tags: wordpress

I want to print the name of the page I am on in Wordpress. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put this in your page template:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

Comment: It is when you know how :)

There is a lot of theme documention available at http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags

Answer (score 0):

in addition,  think you should add the "echo" so it would output or print the title. so goes like:

```
<?php echo the_title(); ?>
```

Comment: By default it is displayed and not returned, if the third parameter is set to false the value is returned and not displayed.

Source:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_title